# Numpy - get "corner" of nd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the upper "corner" or hypertriangle of a fully symmetric numpy nd array.
In other words, i want to slice the array along all its diagonals (with optional offset) and take only the remaining triangle.

```
# with a 3d array and 0 offset, 
a = np.arange(5)
arr=a[:,None,None] + a[None,:,None] + a[None,None,:] 

upper_corner(arr,offset=0)
```

Expected output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 0,  0,  4,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8]],

       [[ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 0,  0,  4,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  4,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

Is there an indexing or slicing solution for this in n-dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) (***tri***angle ***u***pper) can almost do this in one go:

```
>>> np.triu(arr)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 0,  0,  4,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8]],

       [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  0,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  7,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  9]],

       [[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  8,  9],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  9, 10],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 11]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 0,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 0,  0,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 0,  0,  0, 10, 11],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 12]]])
```

But since you seem to want the triangle to move incrementally each time, you can generate an appropriate mask like this:

```
mask = np.array([np.triu(np.ones(arr.shape[1:], dtype=int), i) for i in range(arr.shape[0])])
```

and then multiply the original array by the mask:

```
>>> corners = arr * mask
>>> corners
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 0, 4, 5, 6],
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8]],

       [[0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 0, 4, 5, 6],
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 4, 5, 6],
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: This works nicely, the diagonal offset would then be realized by 
`mask = np.array([np.triu(np.ones(arr.shape[1:], dtype=int), i+k) for i in range(arr.shape[0])])`
where k is the offset

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np
 
arr = np.arange(4**3).reshape(4, 4, 4)
print(arr)
```

It gives:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]]

 [[16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]
  [24 25 26 27]
  [28 29 30 31]]

 [[32 33 34 35]
  [36 37 38 39]
  [40 41 42 43]
  [44 45 46 47]]

 [[48 49 50 51]
  [52 53 54 55]
  [56 57 58 59]
  [60 61 62 63]]]
```

Get the corner:

```
x, y, z = np.ogrid[0:arr.shape[0], 0:arr.shape[1], 0:arr.shape[2]]
arr[x - z + y > 0] = 0
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 0  5  6  7]
  [ 0  0 10 11]
  [ 0  0  0 15]]

 [[ 0 17 18 19]
  [ 0  0 22 23]
  [ 0  0  0 27]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0 34 35]
  [ 0  0  0 39]
  [ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0 51]
  [ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]]
```